# Grails: refresh dependencies

Tags: grails, dependencies

I am using STS and sometimes when I stop my app on a crash it opens up to a hundred different class files that seem to be deep deep inner working stuff.  HTTPBuilder just stopped working, and I suspect its because I accidentally typed in one of these files and absent mindedly saved it.  If I somehow destroyed a local file involved in HTTPBuilder, how would I refresh my dependencies?  (have done install-plugin rest and also uncommented everything in BuildConfig.groovy repositories)

My specific problem and error is here:
[Grails: HTTPBuilder stopped working suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797692/grails-httpbuilder-stopped-working-suddenly)

UPDATE:  As much as I would love to blame STS, as you can see from my answer to my own other question, I was purely thwarted by my own carelessness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had an issue today that we suspect was due to the [Artifactory Migration](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/artifactory-migration).  Your problem may be similar.  The first thing we did to diagnose the issue was to turn up the debug logging in BuildConfig.groovy (change `log "warn"` to `log "debug`").  Once we did that, it was evident that the Grails repos in Artifactory appear to be responding differently to queries made to calculate dependencies.  To workaround these issues, we:

1. Removed grailsCentral, grailsHome, and grailsPlugins from BuildConfig
2. Added `grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"` to BuildConfig
3. Changed one of our dependencies so that its transitive dependencies used specific versions instead of version ranges.

For 3, our specific example was to change:

```
runtime 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.3.4'
```

to

```
runtime 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.3.4', {
            excludes "commons-logging",
                "httpclient", "jackson-core-asl", "jackson-mapper-asl"
        }
runtime 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.7.9' {
        configurationmapping "*->*,!sources,!javadoc"
    }
    runtime 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.7.9' {
        configurationmapping "*->*,!sources,!javadoc"            
    }
```

I'm not sure whether all of these steps were necessary, but they allowed us to move forward.

Comment: Will let you know how this goes, thanks for the in depth solution.

Comment: Also didnt know about `grails refresh-dependencies`, but your advice to change logging plus a little grepping eventually got the problem solved!!