# Grails: HTTPBuilder stopped working suddenly

Tags: grails, httpbuilder

Did not upgrade anything, nothing should have changed, but I may have a silly problem I describe here:
[Grails: refresh dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797680/grails-refresh-dependencies)

HTTPBuilder now gives this error when I try to

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://google.com/' )
```

UPDATE:  I had the wrong error before, this is the error I'm getting when calling that code above in bootstrap.groovy.

```
| Error 2012-03-25 22:50:03,433 [Thread-11] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.resolver.CatalogManager.setIgnoreMissingProperties(Z)V
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.resolver.CatalogManager.setIgnoreMissingProperties(Z)V
Line | Method
->>  290 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    283 | executeForEnvironment            in     ''
|    259 | executeForCurrentEnvironment . . in     ''
|    334 | innerRun                         in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                              in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.resolver.CatalogManager.setIgnoreMissingProperties(Z)V
->>  107 | <clinit>                         in groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistr
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    182 | <init>                           in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
|    204 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     15 | determineConversionFactor        in myproject.AskGoogle
|     14 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
|    290 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    283 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    259 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed a jar that was carelessly added to fix dependencies. It was jaxb-something.