# How to modify the default mapping location of the resources that a Grails plugin uses

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have installed:

```
compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
compile ":jqgrid:3.8.0.1"
```

I got the next error:

```
| Error 2013-06-03 15:20:33,892 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing /plugins/jqgrid-3.8.0.1/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid.css, a resource was required but not found: /plugins/jqgrid-3.8.0.1/css/jqgrid/ellipsis-xbl.xml
```

I opened the file `C:\Users\user\.grails\ivy-cache\org.grails.plugins\jqgrid\zips\jqgrid-3.8.0.1.zip`. There is not any: `css/jqgrid/ellipsis-xbl.xml`

The latest version of JQGrid (4.5.2) has the file ellipsis-xbl.xml included. But I'm using the latest Grails plugin which uses that older version.

**How could I tell Grails to look for ellipsis-xbl.xml in another location (let's say web-app/css/jqgrid-additions/ellipsis-xbl.xml).**

I did a research on Google and it is what could be related:

- [taglib: `<jqgrid:resources />` (according with the documentation, it
  includes the required javascript and css for the plugin)](http://grails.org/plugin/jqgrid)
- [Add a `configurationmapping` in BuildConfig.groovy (I didn't find any
  Grails documentation about that!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797680/grails-refresh-dependencies)
- I added to the GSP the next code to check if it looked at a different
  location (and it check in the same location, at /plugins...):

  `<style>`
     `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {text-overflow:ellipsis; -moz-binding:url('ellipsis-xbl.xml#ellipsis');}`
  `</style>`

Comment: The plugin seems a bit out of date. You could try and ask in the grails mailing list someone to update the plugin or do it yourself. :) Otherwise, you could include the library without using the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I end up by removing all css/js plugins except for jQuery (which is built-in). Just extract css/js files in /web-app directory. Then include them in /grails-app/conf/ApplicationResources.groovy like this:

```
modules = {
  ui {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    resource url: 'css/default.css'
    resource url: 'css/print.css', attrs:[media:'print']
  }
  bootstrap {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    resource url: 'css/bootstrap.css'
    resource url: 'css/bootstrap-responsive.css'
    resource url: 'js/bootstrap.js'
  }
  choice {
    resource url: 'js/choice.js'
  }
  application {
    dependsOn 'jquery,choice'
    resource url: 'js/application.js'
  }
}
```

Choice and application are application specific. Include here as an example. Then, call them in layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="My Application" /></title>
    <g:layoutHead />
    <r:require modules="jquery,ui,bootstrap,choice,application" />
    <r:layoutResources />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <g:layoutBody/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <r:layoutResources />
  </body>
</html>
```

This way, I can manage css/js library myself.